# ¿Es congruente colocar "etc." en un enumeración usando "como"?

Tags: ortografía

En una enumeración de cosas, si coloco "como" y después "etc.", ¿es redundante? Es decir, ¿la palabra "como" indica que son ejemplos los listados además de otros? Entonces, ¿cuál de las siguientes frases es correcta?

- a. Frutas como: naranja, manzana y mango.
- b. Frutas como: naranja, manzana, mango, etc.

Comment: Si quieres limpiar la lista, omitiendo "etc.", quizás sería más claro tu texto así: *Frutas cítricas como por ejemplo naranja, clementina.*

Answer (score 5):

Parece que es redundante. Al menos en [este blog](http://blognisaba.blogspot.com.co/2010/02/etcetera-uso-abuso-y-ortotipografia.html) se puede inferir eso. Primero empiezan describiendo el abuso de dicha expresión, argumentando entre otras cosas que:

> Al mismo tiempo, la libertad que introduce el etcétera es una trampa mortal: el discurso no se cierra, parece que todavía falta mucho por decir y, en el esfuerzo por «rellenar» o «completar» el etcétera, el lector podría cometer cualquier barbaridad

Y más adelante, al mencionar que *como* es una alternativa válida, se entiende que usar los dos al tiempo no es lo más lógico:

> Una estrategia para eliminar por completo el *etcétera* es invocando la figura del ejemplo, cuando solamente se quiere hacer mención de unos pocos casos para orientación del lector. Las fórmulas *entre otros*, *por ejemplo*, *tales como* e incluso ***como*** a secas pueden venir en nuestra ayuda